# I hear a click when i go to start my car... But starts up on second attempt

Tags: engine, electrical, maintenance

Why is my 2009 chevy malibu doing this click before i start it up?

Comment: Not at all... Last time i checked

Comment: When you first put your key in, do you notice anything different than normal operation? Or is it only when you turn the key to start the vehicle?

Comment: Only when i start.

Comment: Only when i turn the key

Comment: There may be a bad connection to the starter solenoid or you may have a bad starter. Have you inspected anything or taken this to a mechanic?

Comment: Not yet... Just was trying to narrow the problem down...

Comment: It did to me last weekend... And just about an hour ago

Comment: When the car does start, does it seem like its trying hard to do so, or is it firing right up?

Comment: It fires right up...

Comment: If you insert the key and just turn it but not to start the car, wait a few seconds and then you keep turning the key to start, does it start at the first attempt?

Answer (score 2):

Your starting system is typically:

(-> represents wires)
Battery -> fuse -> ignition switch -> relay -> starter

The starter also has a direct connection to the battery (big red wire)

The fact that it works the second time means there is likely a loose connection down the line somewhere.  The click you hear is either the relay or the starter solenoid.  Either way, it sounds like you are getting good power to the relay, so your issue lies at the starter.  First is to check for loose connections.  If your connections to the starter are good and tight, then the issue is likely inside the starter.

Answer (score 0):

I was also going to say it could be your solenoid going bad, or loose wire. My solenoid caused my vehicle to do same thing and had to be replaced which was pretty easy had 2 wires n was located on the inside of my firewall.